# Authorization of ADB on Nexus 7 2013 edition

Tags: android, authorization, adb, nexus-7

I was wondering if there is any POSSIBLE way of being able to Authorize the ADB debug on a nexus 7 2013 edition without the touchscreen responding... I've been researching while studying for exams and have yet to find any answer to this problem. I'm able to connect adb but the device remains to be unauthorized, and if no way of doing it i'll try to do restart my device when it dies after a battery drain...

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is any POSSIBLE way of being able to Authorize the ADB debug on a nexus 7 2013 edition without the touchscreen responding

Fortunately, no. The point behind putting the dialog there was for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `update.zip` to add your key to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`. You might have to root and flash custom recovery first though.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't understand what you are looking for but AFAIR, there is a checkbox in this dialog to "Allways authorize this computer".